# Query MySQL Group by and Having

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating an application for my school and I am in trouble constructing the right query.

I have 2 tables,table1 and table2.

table1

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| StudentID  | SubjectID   | Present        | Type      |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 2          | 3           | yes            |  1        |
| 2          | 2           | yes            |  2        |
| 3          | 1           | no             |  3        |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

table2

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| SubjectID  | SubjectName | Number1        | Number2   |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | Name1       | 6              |  4        |
| 2          | Name2       | 4              |  8        |
| 3          | Name3       | 5              |  2        |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

SubjectID in table1 is foreign key references table2.

I want to build a query sql that gives me the StudentID`s from table1
that didnt miss any Type 3 subject (i.e no row like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| StudentID  | SubjectID   | Present        | Type      |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 3          | 1           | no             |  3        |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

And have completed 75 percent of type 1 (i.e
I find it like this

```
SELECT t1.StudentID,t1.SubjectID ,t1.Type,t2.Number1 as num
FROM table1 as t1,table2 as t2
WHERE t1.Present=yes and t2.SubjectID=t1.SubjectID
GROUP BY StudentID,SubjectID
HAVING COUNT(*)/num >= 75/100
```

But I cant combine the two things together.

Comment: Please update your post with better design. It's hard to read. Put code in a code sample.

Comment: If Type is a property of Subject, why is that column not in the second table?

Comment: Also, what does 75% of Type 1 mean? Is it 75% of at least one Type 1 Subject? 75% of all Type 1 Subjects? at least 75% of *every* Type 1 Subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine queries by giving them aliases and joining as subqueries...

```
SELECT finisher.StudentID FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT StudentID
    FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.SubjectID = t1.SubjectID
    WHERE t1.Present = 'yes' AND t1.Type1 = 1
    GROUP BY t1.StudentID, t2.SubjectID
    HAVING COUNT(*) / t2.Number2 >= 0.75
) finisher
JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.StudentID
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN
    ( 
        SELECT DISTINCT StudentID 
        FROM table1 
        WHERE Type = 3 AND Present = 'no'
    ) missed ON missed.StudentID = t1.StudentID
    WHERE t1.Type = 3
    AND missed.StudentID IS NULL
) notmissed ON finisher.StudentID = notmissed.StudentID
```

"StudentID`s from table1 that didnt miss any Type 3"... I assume here you don't want to include students without any type 3 rows.

Comment: Requires three separate accesses of `table1`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is done and duste, but how about...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM
     ( SELECT t1.StudentID
            , t1.SubjectID 
            , t1.Type
            , t2.Number1 num
         FROM table1 t1
         JOIN table2 t2   
           ON t2.SubjectID=t1.SubjectID
        WHERE t1.Present='yes' 
        GROUP 
           BY t1.StudentID
            , t1.SubjectID
       HAVING COUNT(*)/num >= 0.75
     ) x
  LEFT
  JOIN table1 y
    ON y.student_id = x.student_id
   AND y.subject_id = x.subject_id
   AND y.type = 3
   AND y.present = 'no'
 WHERE y.student_id IS NULL;
```